# MVC How To Pass Url Values as Well as a Model From Action to a View

Tags: forms, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, view, controller

I am looking for a way to preserve a url parameter after posting through a form. For example my GET method takes a string "type" and uses that to determine the type of report to render in the View. The url looks like this:

```
http://mysite/Reports/Report?type=1

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Report(string type)
      {
         var model = new ReportsModel()
          {  
             Report = ReportList.Find(o => o.ReportType == type)
          };

          return View(model);             
       }
```

The View has a form that has start/end date filters used to determine the date range of the date to be displayed for the type of report:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Report", "Reports"))
   {
        Report.ReportName
        @Html.HiddenFor(o => o.Report.ReportType)
        @Html.EditorFor(o => o.Report.StartDate )<br/>
        @Html.EditorFor(o => o.Report.EndDate )<br/>
        <button id="reports">Report</button>
   }
```

The above form posts to an action that gets report data from the database based on the specified report type, start/end dates, and returns back to the view.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Report(GenericReportsModel model)
        {
            switch (model.Report.ReportType)
            {
                case ReportType.ReportType1:
                    model.Result = ReportRepository.GetReport<ReportType1>(model.StartDate, model.EndDate);
                    break;
                case ReportType.ReportType2:
                    model.Result = ReportRepository.GetReport<ReportType2>(model.StartDate, model.EndDate);
                    break;                    
            }    
            return View(model);
        }
```

The problem is that after the post, the "type" parameter is lost from the url.

```
Before the post: http://mysite/Reports/Report?type=1 
After the post: http://mysite/Reports/Report
```

I need to be able to do something like this (which doesn't work):

```
 return View(model, new {ReportType = model.ReportType);
```

How can I preserve the type parameter in the url after the post, in case someone wants to copy and paste the url to send to someone else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update `Html.BeginForm` and your `HttpPost` version of Report method.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Report", "Report", "YourController", new { type = model.ReportType})
{
    // I am assuming that model.ReportType == type argument 
    // in your HttpGet Report action

    // The rest of the form goes here
}
```

Your action should look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Report(string type, GenericReportsModel model)
{
    switch (model.Report.ReportType)
    {
        case ReportType.ReportType1:
            model.Result = ReportRepository.GetReport<ReportType1>(model.StartDate, model.EndDate);
            break;
        case ReportType.ReportType2:
            model.Result = ReportRepository.GetReport<ReportType2>(model.StartDate, model.EndDate);
            break;                    
    }    
    return View(model);
}
```

If `type` is not equal to model.ReportType then you should create a ViewModel that contains the values from your `GenericsReportModel` and this other Report type.